# How to convert string(float) into number without adding exponential (e)

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript

I'm trying to convert string into number but it is adding exponential symbol. I'm expecting the same output but in number not in string.

I have tried `toFixed()`, but it is returning string.

For example

```
var x = "0.00000001";
+x.toFixed(8);
console.log(x); // Actual Output: "0.00000001" | Expected output: 0.00000001
```

```
Sample code
var x = "0.00000001";
+x; // output: 1e-8
```

Actual Output: "0.00000001"

Expected output: 0.00000001

Comment: that is just how JavaScript expresses large (as in lots of digits) numbers. it's still just a plain old number. you can do math with it or convert it back to a string to view it in long form.

Comment: `0.00000001` *is* `1e-8`. It's literally the same value. If you need the value formatted for display, then use a string, if you want to use mathematical operations, then it doesn't matter how JS formats the numeric value.

Answer (score 1):

If you print a number without formatting, the javascript interpeter decides the format. It tries to select a short format with respect to the precision.
So `0.00000001` is printed as `1e-8`.

Code analysis:

```
var x = "0.00000001";
```

Here yo assign a string to `x`.

```
+x.toFixed(8);
```

This should throw an error for the part `x.toFixed(8)`, because `toFixed()` is not defined for string. Maybe you wanted:

```
(+x).toFixed(8);
```

The plus sign converts the string into a number, and then `toFixed(8)` creates a formatted string for that number. The result is not used in any way (expect console output).

```
console.log(x);
```

In the line before, you didn't changed the value of `x`. So it's still the assigned string of the first line and you get the correct `"0.00000001"`

Comment: Your result is same as input, which is wrong because this will again returns the string not the number.

Comment: Do you read my comment especially the last sentence? You assigned a string to x, don't modify x and print x. So the output of x is still a string. And the debugging (!) function `console.log()` reflects the string type by quotes. If you assign x to a input element like `input.value = x` the input box don't show the quotes.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```js
  var oldString = '0.00000001';
  var oldNumber = Number('0.00000001');
   const str = oldNumber.toString();

    const exponent = parseInt(str.split('-')[1], 10);
    const result = oldNumber.toFixed(exponent);
    console.log(result);
```

Comment: How does this "fix" the problem? `oldNumber` is still represented as `1e-8`. The OP already knows how to use `toFixed` to get a string representation.

Comment: Old Number doesn't but result does it is explained here follow them  for better explanations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-to-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: Answers should be self-contained; I should be able to understand your answer and how it relates to the question without visiting another question. Also, that question has nothing to do with this one; it's about floating point accuracy when doing mathematical operations. This one demonstrates a lack of understanding of how numbers are stored in JavaScript.

Comment: sorry for the inconvenience I will get back to you soon

Comment: I have already tried `.toFixed()` and the problem is it will return output string datatype but I need number datatype.